# The deployment contains process definitions with the same key (process id atrribute), this is not allowed

Tags: activiti

I implement three .bpmn files in the single project and while running i get this    exception `org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException:The deployment contains process definitions with the same key (process id atrribute), this is not allowed` Can u explain where I did mistake? There is any possibility to run more than one .bpmn    file in single project and how it is?

Answer (score 2):

Error description provides enough information to locate this issue. Activti database table `act_re_procdef` already contains record with the same id because you have deployed same .bpmn file earlier . You can:

1. drop and create this table using scripts from Activiti jar (package `org.activiti.db.drop`)
2. change `<process id="vacationProcess" name="vacation process" isExecutable="true">`
   `id` attribute in your process definition
3. Change process definition itself to make Activiti engine redeploy process definition with new version (see `act_re_procdef`)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I am using activiti along with spring.

I added following config to re-deploy the process:

```
  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
<property name="deploymentMode" value="single-resource" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue, I simply removed all the processes.bpmn20.xml and forms.jsons from my processes folder  on my server and redeployed my processes.
Note: you can also rename the current processes folder to any other name and create a new processes folder.